# How to set window owner from another thread

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870.aspx) library, in this topic: "Multiple Windows, Multiple Threads", this is the code given:

```
<Window x:Class="SDKSamples.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MultiBrowse"
Height="600" 
Width="800"
Loaded="OnLoaded"
>
<StackPanel Name="Stack" Orientation="Vertical">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
  <Button Content="New Window"
          Click="NewWindowHandler" />
  <TextBox Name="newLocation"
           Width="500" />
  <Button Content="GO!"
          Click="Browse" />
</StackPanel>
<Frame Name="placeHolder"
        Width="800"
        Height="550"></Frame>
</StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Code behind:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using System.Threading;


namespace SDKSamples
{
public partial class Window1 : Window
{

    public Window1() : base()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       placeHolder.Source = new Uri("http://www.msn.com");
    }

    private void Browse(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        placeHolder.Source = new Uri(newLocation.Text);
    }

    private void NewWindowHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {       
        Thread newWindowThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadStartingPoint));
        newWindowThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        newWindowThread.IsBackground = true;
        newWindowThread.Start();
    }
    private void ThreadStartingPoint()
    {
        Window1 tempWindow = new Window1();
        tempWindow.Show();       
        System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run();
    }
}
}
```

How do I set the owner of tempWindow to the Main Window? I have multiple windows in my application which need to be updated simultaneously for which I want to use this.

Comment: Have you considered using data binding and implementing INotifyPropertyChanged instead?

Comment: @failedprogramming: I am working on someone else's code. It's all already written and very long and tedious to change the code..:(

Comment: ok that is fair enough. If you want to make changes to a control from another thread, I think you will need to create a delegate and invoke using the dispatcher of the control.